# Pattern for Compositions of Abstract Objects

Tags: java, abstract-class, composition, concreteclass

I have an abstract class that has an array of abstract things:

```
Abstract Color has abstract ColorThings[]
```

I have several concrete classes that each have an array of concrete things:

```
Concrete RedColor has concrete RedThings[]
Concrete BlueColor has concrete BlueThings[]
```

All are related:

```
RedColor and BlueColor are Colors.  
RedThings[] and BlueThings[] are ColorThings[].
```

What design pattern do I need here? I already have a factory method going on, where any Color sub-class must be able to generate an appropriate ColorThing. However, I'd also like to be able to have this method in Color, which sub-classes would not need to implement:

```
addColorThing(ColorThing thing) {/*ColorThing[] gets RedThing or BlueThing*/}
```

Additionally, I'd like each sub-class to be able to instantiate the super.ColorThings[] as their own version of the array:

```
class RedColor {
    colorThings[] = new RedThings[];
}
```

Does Java allow for any of this? Can I redesign any of it better?

Comment: By the way, you may want to look into using List instead of arrays, as arrays aren't resizable (IIRC).

Comment: This would best be represented as a generic [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

Comment: Thanks, am in fact using LinkedList, just wanted to simplify the question as much as I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics will let you do what you want:

```
abstract class Color<T extends ColorThings> {
    protected T[] things;
}

class RedColor extends Color<RedThings> {
}

// And so on.
```

The idea here is that each subclass of `Color` needs to declare what specific subclass of `ColorThings` they use. By using the type parameter `T`, you can achieve this.

[Read more in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)...

Comment: Much happy, wow, very perfection. After I got my various interfaces all playing nicely with each other, anyway. THANK YOU.